# How can I change the boarding station for the Nagpur-Pune Express?

Tags: indian-railways, train-stations

I have booked a Tatkal ticket from Nagpur to Pune with the Nagpur-Pune Express, but I have to board from Wardha. I will be traveling on the 9th of May 2016. How can I change the boarding station?

Comment: Welcome to Travel! I've made quite an edit to your post that tries to make it more readable and more structured. I assumed you are traveling tomorrow rather than in September, so I wrote out the full date to avoid confusion. If you think I changed the meaning of your post, you can improve or roll back the edit.